# contour plot with mutiplile files

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I have a sequence of data files which contain two columns of data (x value, and z value). I want to asign each file with a unique constant y value with a loop and then use x,y,z values to make a contour plot.

```
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

files=glob.glob('C:\Users\DDT\Desktop\DATA TIANYU\materials\AB2O4\synchronchron\OX1\YbFe1Mn1O4_2cyc_600_meth_ox1-*.xye')
s1=1
for file in files:
    t1=s1/3
    x,z = np.loadtxt(file,skiprows=3,unpack=True, usecols=[0,1])
    def f(x, y):
     return x*0 +y*0 +z
    l1=np.size(x)
    y=np.full(l1, t1,dtype=int)
    X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
    Z = f(X,Y)
    plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
    s1=s1+1
    continue
plt.show()
```

There is no error in this code, however what I got is an empty figure with nothing.

What mistake did I make?

Comment: Your function f `x*0 +y*0 +z` is very weird. Also, the `continue` statement is strange, as the default behavior of a `for` loop is just to continue. `y=np.full(x.size, t1,dtype=int)` creates a y array full of zeros (when t1=1/3 and converted to integer). From the code it is extremely hard to guess what you're trying to do.  Your data doesn't seem to be very inappropriate for a contour plot, even if you would change the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do Z=f(x,y) in order to make z into a 2d array so that plt.contour can work. I also tried to use:
xi = np.linspace(0, 15, 10)
yi = np.linspace(-100, 1000, 10)
zi = matplotlib.mlab.griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi).   But it gave me an error: RuntimeError: Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: singular input data (exitcode=2); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error.

Comment: Since my data file doesn't have y value and I want to create a constant y value for each data file, I have to use '''y=np.full(x.size, t1,dtype=int)''' to generate y value so that I can plot XYZ.

Comment: You should really start with plotting your data as a scatter plot: `plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)`. Once that works you could try more complicated things. A contour plot only makes sense if your calculated `y` are a real dimension of your data.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to guess what you're trying to do. Here is an attempt. It supposes that all x-arrays are equal. And that the y really makes sense (although that is hard if the files are read in an unspecified order). To get a useful plot, the data from all the files should be collected before starting to plot.

```py
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

files = glob.glob('........')
zs = []
for file in files:
    x, z = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=3, unpack=True, usecols=[0, 1])
    zs.append(z)
# without creating a new x, the x from the last file will be used
# x = np.linspace(0, 15, 10) 
y = np.linspace(-100, 1000, len(zs))
zs = np.array(zs)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
axs[0].scatter(np.tile(x, y.size), np.repeat(y, x.size), c=zs)
axs[1].contour(x, y, zs)

plt.show()
```

With simulated random data, the scatter plot and the contour plot would look like:

[image: resulting plot]